# edge invisibility in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to know how can we make edge invisble in tikz ( similar to visible). 
Here is my code. I am able to add edges (1,4) and (4,5) using visible command, at the same time I want to remove the edge (1,5), which I am unable to do it. Kindly help me.

```
\begin{tikzpicture
 [scale=.5,auto=left,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,every                 node/.style={circle,fill=blue!60}]
\node (n1)[fill=red] at (0,0)  {1};
\node (n2) at (2,0)  {2};
\node (n3) at (0,2)  {3};
\node (n4)[fill=red] at (2,2)  {4};
\node (n5)[fill=red] at (4,-2)  {5};
\foreach \from/\to  in {n1/n2,n1/n5,n1/n3,n2/n4,n2/n5,n3/n4}
\draw (\from) -- (\to);
\invisible<2->{ (n1) to  (n5);}
\visible<2->{\draw (n1) to  (n4);}
\visible<2->{\draw (n4) to (n5);}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If `\visible` works fro `(n1) to (n4)`, use it. Supress `n1/n5` from `foreach` and add `\visible<1>{\draw (n1) to (n5)};}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `\visible` command is from `beamer` not `tikz`. you can do that with a third variable `\anim` inside `\foreach` loop to control apparence of edges.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [scale=.5,auto=left,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!60}]
\node (n1)[fill=red] at (0,0)  {1};
\node (n2) at (2,0)  {2};
\node (n3) at (0,2)  {3};
\node (n4)[fill=red] at (2,2)  {4};
\node (n5)[fill=red] at (4,-2)  {5};
\foreach \from/\to/\anim  in {n1/n2/1-,n1/n5/1,n1/n3/1-,n1/n4/2-,n2/n4/1-,n2/n5/1-,n3/n4/1-,n4/n5/2-}
{\visible<\anim>{\draw (\from) -- (\to);}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```